# Extract the breadcrumbs of a website using selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath, web-scraping, css-selectors, webdriverwait

i need to extract the breadcrumbs of this website site: https://www.woolworths.com.au/Shop/Browse/drinks/cordials-juices-iced-teas/iced-teas

I tried to inspect the element and copy the xpath but it doesn't extract it

```py
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.woolworths.com.au/Shop/Browse/drinks/cordials-juices-iced-teas/iced-teas')
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="center-panel"]/div/wow-tile-list-with-content/ng-transclude/wow-browse-tile-list/wow-tile-list/div/div[1]/div[1]/wow-breadcrumbs/div/ul/li[4]/span/span')

driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#center-panel > div > wow-tile-list-with-content > ng-transclude > wow-browse-tile-list > wow-tile-list > div > div.tileList > div.tileList-headerContainer > wow-breadcrumbs > div > ul > li:nth-child(4) > span > span')
```

How can I proceed?

Comment: what error you getting please add error to question

Comment: I have an empty list for the xpath command and for the css selector i have :  Message: Unable to locate element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print the breadcrumbs of the website site: https://www.woolworths.com.au/Shop/Browse/drinks/cordials-juices-iced-teas/iced-teas you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and `get_attribute()` method:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul.breadcrumbs-linkList li:nth-child(4) span span"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and `text` property:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='breadcrumbs-linkList']//following-sibling::li[4]//span//span"))).text)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Outro

As per the documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)

Answer (score 1):

The page you are trying to scrape is written in Angular, meaning that most of the `DOM element`s are loaded dynamically by JavaScript AJAX code  and they are not present once the page is loaded. (`driver.get` function returns)

You should use [waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)  `until` function to locate such elements.

Here is the working example using the XPATH you provided:

```
driver.get('https://www.woolworths.com.au/Shop/Browse/drinks/cordials-juices-iced-teas/iced-teas')
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="center-panel"]/div/wow-tile-list-with-content/ng-transclude/wow-browse-tile-list/wow-tile-list/div/div[1]/div[1]/wow-breadcrumbs/div/ul/li[4]/span/span'))
    )
    print(element.text) ' this outputs Iced Teas
except TimeoutException:
    print("Timeout")
```

Answer (score 0):

Below one works for my validation

`//*[span='first text' and span='Search results for "second text"']`

Comment: Hi Sukumar and Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please format your code? You can read here on [how to format your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and here on [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), thanks!